# I don't understand the explanation to the answer of this practice composition question. Can someone advise

Tags: subjects

**Explanation:** "Each" is a singular subject. The possessive noun "pageant's" as well as the following pronoun should also be singular.

**Question:**("All of this requires hard work, determination, and taking the time to research each beauty pageants rules as well as their history.") **should be rewritten as follows:**

**Answer:** All of this requires hard work, determination, and taking the time to research each beauty pageant's rules as well as its history.

It makes sense now, however i'm still perplexed. How would I have known to locate "each"  and not "pageant's" as the sentence's subject?

Comment: "All of this" is the sentence's subject.

Comment: Not according to the explanation of the answer, written by the test makers.

Comment: The main subject of the sentence is actually *all of this* (requires x, y, and z). However, the subject in the last part is not *each* or *pageant*, it's *each beauty pageant*.

Comment: So am i correct in saying "pageant's" is the possessive noun and the subject?

Comment: When referring to the possessive, the subject is still *each beauty pageant*. The object of the possession (what is possessed) is *rules*.

Comment: @IanSimons _Pageant_ is the head of the noun phrase _each beauty pageant_, which has the possessive clitic _-‘s_ attached to it to make it possessive. The explanation you quote makes an error often made by people who haven’t studied grammar, namely using the term ‘subject’ (which is a specific thing) to refer to just any noun (or in this case, it seems, any word at all, since _each_ is a determinative). The only subject in your sentence is the noun phrase _all of this_; the beauty pageant is not the subject of any verb in your sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The "**Explanation**" that you quote is mistaken. The use of *each, pageant's* and *its* in this sentence has nothing to do with subjects. The word *each* functions as a determiner of the 
"nominal"* *beauty pageant* in the possessive noun phrase *each beauty pageant's*, which is used as the determiner of the larger noun phrase *each beauty pageant's rules*, which is used as the object of the verb *research.*

The correct explanation would be that *each beauty pageant('s)* is the **antecedent** of the personal pronoun *its.*

Whenever *each* is used as a determiner, it goes with a singular noun. That's just the way the *each [noun]* construction works in English.

---

* in the terminology of the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language,* "nominal" refers to a constituent like *beauty pageant* that is smaller than a complete noun phrase but larger than a single isolated noun.